# Import content to ckeditor correctly

Tags: 8, wysiwyg

I imported large number of articles from another CMS to Drupal 8.

The content is in HTML and when i open a page i have html not interpreted.

How do i tell Drupal/Ckeditor that the content is in HTML ?

For now the only thing working is when i edit an article and clic on source twice to get the HTML interpreted but i can't do that to the large number of articles that i have.

Answer (score 1):

It was simple after all in the table node__body there is body_format and you should set it to full-html